# Cannot run block in pl/sql getting ora-06550 and pls-00103

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to make anonymous blocks to update esri's oracle versioned views. The code runs fine when I execute it from pl/sql developer without the begin/end. But as soon as I add the begin/end I get errors.

```
begin
call sde.version_util.set_current_version ('ARCFM8.vtemp');
call sde.version_user_ddl.edit_version ('ARCFM8.vtemp', 1);

update arcfm8.t_conductormarker_vw set CEAREFERENCEDRAWING = 'my fisrt multiversion view update'
where OBJECTID = 3;

call sde.version_user_ddl.edit_version ('ARCFM8.vtemp', 2);
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call is an SQL keyword not a PLSQL keyword. It will work outside the anonymous block, but not inside it.  PLSQL will take care of this for you so all you should need is...

```
begin
 sde.version_util.set_current_version ('ARCFM8.vtemp');
 sde.version_user_ddl.edit_version ('ARCFM8.vtemp', 1);

 update arcfm8.t_conductormarker_vw set CEAREFERENCEDRAWING = 'my fisrt multiversion view update' where OBJECTID = 3;

 sde.version_user_ddl.edit_version ('ARCFM8.vtemp', 2);
end;
```

Comment: A point of clarification: `CALL` is a command in Oracle's SQL*Plus command-line database client - it is not an SQL statement.